# Who are the major authors in Information Extraction, Text Mining and Natural Language Processing area?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, information-extraction

This is not a code question, but about concepts. I want to know who are the main author/researches for Information Extraction, Natural Language Processing and Text Mining to read his papers/books/works.

Comment: What have you found so far?  For instance, what did a search on Amazon turn up for the best selling or highest rated books on NLP, information retrieval, etc.?  This is quite a subjective / poll question, unfortunately, so it's hard to say what's right.  It's better, on SO, to focus on specific goals.

Comment: Maybe this should be community wiki about computer linguistic book/reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find very good references on Quora under:

[What are the most important research papers which all NLP students should definitely read?](http://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing/What-are-the-most-important-research-papers-which-all-NLP-students-should-definitely-read?q=best%20papers%20natural%20lan)

Answer (score 2):

While not a definitive list, the [ACL Anthology Network](http://clair.si.umich.edu/clair/anthology/rankings.cgi) has a list of rankings that give you a sense of what papers are frequently cited in Computational Linguistics.

Answer (score 1):

For me, [Daniel Jurafsky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873210), [Christopher Manning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521865719) and [Tom Mitchell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070428077).

Comment: Mitchell's specialization is ML, not as much NLP; although he has collaborated on projects like NELL.

Comment: Yes he is. I include Mitchell since a lot of concepts I learned in Mitchell book are incorporated in NLP.

Answer (score 1):

Stanford is offering an online class on natural language processing. Visit http://www.nlp-class.org/

Answer (score 1):

Look at The Handbook of Data Mining - Nong Ye for a collection of many papers. This should also point you to the key researchers in text/data mining.

[http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Mining-Human-Factors-Ergonomics/dp/0805855637/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1328297313&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805855637)

I for the record own this book.